# How to get string out of List js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am pretty new to JS and I am trying to code a discord bot. Now i have a question:

If i have a list like this:

````
    {
      names: [ 'kick' ],
      category: 'Moderation',
      description: 'Kicks a user',
      syntax: '<User> <Reason>',
      hidden: false,
      testOnly: true
    }
    {
      names: [ 'send' ],
      category: 'Config',
      description: 'Sends a message.',
      syntax: '<channel> <text>',
      hidden: false,
      testOnly: true
    }
    {
      names: [ 'timeout' ],
      category: 'Moderation',
      description: 'Times out a user',
      syntax: '<User> <Time>',
      hidden: false,
      testOnly: true
    }``` (this is all a variable)
how can i get for example every command that has the Moderation catagory?
So that i have them in an array.
````

Comment: Please tidy up your question. Are those objects in an array? If so can you present them as such and include the commas. And include any code you're attempted yourself?

Comment: By the time this is tidied up, it'll just be a duplicate.

Comment: @CYPS84 No doubt! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the title you only want a string array of the command names.

```js
let disCommands = [ { names: [ 'kick' ], category: 'Moderation', description: 'Kicks a user', syntax: '<User> <Reason>', hidden: false, testOnly: true }, { names: [ 'send' ], category: 'Config', description: 'Sends a message.', syntax: '<channel> <text>', hidden: false, testOnly: true }, { names: [ 'timeout' ], category: 'Moderation', description: 'Times out a user', syntax: '<User> <Time>', hidden: false, testOnly: true } ]

let modCommands = disCommands.filter(c => c.category === 'Moderation').flatMap(c => c.names);
console.log(modCommands);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
list.filter(x=>x.category==="Moderation")
```

should do the trick

please read up on  [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to learn more

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter method to filter selectedItems.

```
var myList =     {
      names: [ 'kick' ],
      category: 'Moderation',
      description: 'Kicks a user',
      syntax: '<User> <Reason>',
      hidden: false,
      testOnly: true
    }
    {
      names: [ 'send' ],
      category: 'Config',
      description: 'Sends a message.',
      syntax: '<channel> <text>',
      hidden: false,
      testOnly: true
    }
    {
      names: [ 'timeout' ],
      category: 'Moderation',
      description: 'Times out a user',
      syntax: '<User> <Time>',
      hidden: false,
      testOnly: true
    }
var selectedCommands = myList.filter(value => value.category == 'Moderation')
```